# Calling JS api in Elixir

Tags: javascript, elixir

I need a payment functionality in my website, the payment is done via some third party organization which exposes its api which is in JS. So my question is how do i interact with their api if it's written in JS?

Comment: Why do you need to interact with it in Elixir? Wouldn’t it make sense to use it on the browser?

Comment: @depa The reason is I want to write the backend in Elixir and frontend in Elm. So I need to process the payments in my Elixir code. Am I clear?

Comment: Is this JS that was developed for the browser, or is it JS that was developed for the server? If it is meant for the browser, you should consider making an Elm wrapper for it.

Comment: @JustinWood It's a website like PayPal. It gives you a small SDK for processing payments. I don't know how to interact with the sdk from my Elixir code. I don't know, maybe I'm not explaining well. It's like you have a pay button in your page, you push the button and it goes to this third party website, you enter bank card info and pay, then it comes back to your website after payment.

Comment: You will need to lookup the documentation for your service. Without knowing what service it is, I can't say how you can setup your project and what to expect from their request. As for calling the JavaScript from your elixir code, I am unaware of a way to do that. However, if it is anything like stripe, they give you some JavaScript to run on the client (you would call it from Elm) and you would build the server in any language and just respond to them how they expect. There would not call the JS code from your server.

Comment: There is too much uncertainty between your problem as described and the solution. The solution to this problem requires knowing a lot of steps in between. Try breaking the problem up and asking a focused question about the first step.

Answer (score 2):

What often happens is that the payment gateway will provide a JavaScript drop-in that tokenizes the credit card data and inserts a hidden element into a form on your page.  When that form gets submitted to your server, in your Elixir code you can use the token you were given to make API calls to the gateway to complete the purchase.

Depending on how popular the gateway is, there might be an Elixir API wrapper for it already, or you may have to make one.  But it sounds like you're stuck on the first part, which is how to interact with this third party from the browser, so you might want to tag another question with Elm and be more specific about what third party you're trying to interact with.